# Python: how to improve efficency load data from vfp(dbf) to oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, dbf

all.
I use python load data from dbf(vfp) file to oracle db.But,the efficency is not good.the record 7,000,000 cost 40minutes.Only I want to reduce the loop,this is the key point.the code below:

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle
from dbfpy.dbf import *

dbhost=sys.argv[1]
dbport=sys.argv[2]
dbsid=sys.argv[3]
dbuser=sys.argv[4]
dbpasswd=sys.argv[5]
schema=sys.argv[6]
tbname=sys.argv[7]
vdate=sys.argv[8]
organ=0
gap=5000

tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dbhost,dbport,dbsid)
db = cx_Oracle.connect(dbuser,dbpasswd,tns)
execsql = 'truncate table ' + schema + '.' + tbname
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(execsql)

count=0
param=[];
execsql='insert into '+ schema + '.' + tbname + ' values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11)'
dbf = Dbf("E:\abc.dbf")
for rec in dbf:
    param.append((vdate,rec['ZQ'],rec['TZ'],rec['TX'],rec['ZJ'],rec['ZJM'],rec['CQ'],rec['DH'],rec['RQ'],rec['ZZT'],rec['DXW']))
    count += 1
    if count >= gap:
        cur.executemany(execsql,param);
        db.commit()
        param=[]    
        count = organ 

if param:
    cur.executemany(execsql,param);
    db.commit()
cur.close()
db.close()
dbf.close()
```

can everyone help me improve the efficency?

Comment: Most of the time is probably spent sending small amount of data back and forth.  Batching the inserts, for example by combining 10 inserts into a single statement like `insert into table select '1'... from dual union all select '2' ... from dual` can often make these processes run several times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does Oracle support reading data from `.csv` files?  If so, check out [my dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) to create a `.csv` file with the necessary fields (something like this (untested)):

```
import dbf

with dbf.Table(r'c:\abc.dbf') as t:
    dbf.export(t, field_names='ZQ, TZ, TX, ZJ, ZJM, CQ, DH, RQ, ZZT, DXW')
```

This will create `c:\abc.csv` with the data from those fields.

Comment: I think i see you meaning.first generate dbf file to csv file,second user sqlldr load the csv file into oracle?i am afraid that generate the csv file may cost much time.whatever,i will try it soon.thank you so much